# Display video files in listview from sdcard folder

Tags: android, listview, video, sd-card

I am trying to display video files in listview from folder 'abc' on sdcard, i have successfully displayed but problem is that it displays all video files stored on sdcard even out of folder 'abc' actually i want only video files stored in folder 'abc' to be displayed. I am googling since more days but didn't find any solution for that. My code is:

```
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
proj, null, null, null);
count = videocursor.getCount();
videolist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
videolist.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
videolist.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
}
private OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View v, int position,
long id) {
System.gc();
video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
String filename = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
Intent intent = new Intent(VideoActivity.this, ViewVideo.class);
intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
startActivity(intent);
}
};

public class VideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context vContext;
public VideoAdapter(Context c) {
vContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
return count;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
System.gc();
TextView tv = new TextView(vContext.getApplicationContext());
String id = null;
if (convertView == null) {
video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
videocursor.moveToPosition(position);
id = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);
tv.setText(id);
} 
else
{
tv = (TextView) convertView;
return tv;
}
```

Any Hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you got any solution ? i am also facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the content provider in this case. The content provider will give you info on all the videos that it can find on your device.

Write your own little utility to scan and pick up the files/folders that you require.

Comment: But i have given also path of '/sdcard/abc", but still display all video files.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a filtering criteria to the managed query that filters for your folder name.

Look at the [javadoc for the method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29). It has criteria for the selection of records. That should allow you to select your desired subset.

Comment: How can i provide filtering criteria? i have tried Uri a = Uri.parse("/sdcard/abc") and videocursor=managedQuery(a,
proj, null, null, null); but still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Dont Use This following code:

video_column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);

Edit This code with the following code:

videocursor = MainActivity.this.managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",new String[] {"%abc%"},null);

THIS WILL HELP YOU FOR SURE.......