# How do i exclude a specific path from searching via managedQuery usig cursors android

Tags: android

Hi i am a newbie in android & had fallen under this fix.

What i am supposed to do is to search for all the videos (mp4 format) stored in the SD Card of the device. Here the only condition that i need to stick with is that, it should not look into the specified folder & its sub-child but others only. So far what i have done brings the result of all the videos stored on the SD card including the folder to be excluded. Once this is achieved i had to choose the file from the thumbnails & retrieve its path & perform any further operations over it. How can i exclude any specific path from the content Uri specified? Below is my code

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

For reference i had looked into this query as well [Display video files in listview from sdcard folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733983/display-video-files-in-listview-from-sdcard-folder)
but unfortunately didnt solve my concern as i had to stick with the managedQuery concept.

```
public class BrowseActivity extends Activity {
//set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
private GridView galleryView;
private Cursor cursor;
private int columnIndex;
private int[] videosId;
private Uri contentUri;

protected Context context;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);
    //set GridView for gallery
    galleryView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    //set default as external/sdcard uri
    contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    showToast("contentUri is---------:- "+contentUri);
    //initialize the videos uri
    initVideosId();
    //set gallery adapter
    setGalleryAdapter();
}

private void setGalleryAdapter() {
    galleryView.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(context));
    galleryView.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);
    showToast("Gallery Adapter Set ");
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        System.gc();
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
                proj,   // Which columns to return
                null,   // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,   // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null);  // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        // We want to get the column index for the data uri
        // int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
        // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String filename = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        showToast("Your Selection is:- "+filename);
    }
};

private void initVideosId() {
    try {           
        //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
        String [] proj={_ID};
        // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
        cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
                proj,   // Which columns to return
                null,   // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,   // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null);  // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int count= cursor.getCount();
        // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        videosId = new int[count];
        //move position to first element
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            videosId[i]= id;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
}

protected void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return videosId.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(context);
        try {
            if(convertView!=null) {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
            imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("BrowseActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imgVw;
    }

    // Create the thumbnail on the fly
    private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
        Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getContentResolver(),
                id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        return thumb;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a `WHERE` clause that will perform your filtering and supply that `WHERE` clause to `managedQuery()` where you are presently supplying `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response on this. could you please let me how exactly the where clause could be supplied to filter the uri if the folder i wish to exclude is "/mnt/sdcard/folder" & its sub-folders. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks CommonWare for your valuable suggestion, the reason i asked you for a sample where clause is i just this that i was not aware what shalli mention in the where clause like column name etc.

However after many worth full efforts, I finally have an example that works & does exactly what i meant it to do. Now i am able to query the Device excluding any particular folder. 
I just thought I'd share it.

I just made some changes in my query being triggered

```
cursor = managedQuery(contentUri,
            proj,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " not like ? ",
            new String[] {"%excludeFolder%"},
            null);
```

where %excludeFolder% refers to path eg /mnt/sdcard/excludeFolder & its sub child.
Also a point to be noted is that the query is not like so it excludes this from search.

However this is the way i had achieved, if there is any other better options the question is still open to pour in your valuable replies.

***PS:- Please Rate/Vote the rely if you like it & it solves your concern. ***

Thanks.